# How to properly export an object.fbx to UE4?

Tags: export, import, .fbx, unreal-engine

I'll show you step by step what I do, from the creation of the object, to its import into UE4. Maybe it's some small detail that's making it go wrong. In this explanation I will prefer to sin for the excess of information:

1.1 - I get the initial Cube from Blender and I split it in half. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

1.2 - Then I activate mirror modifier on the cube.

[image]

2.1 - I make some adjustments in your size. <kbd>S</kbd>

2.2 - I start making the extrusions. <kbd>E</kbd>

2.3 - I make the neck and finally the head.

[image]

3.1 - I define a space where the arms will be extruded. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

3.2 - I make the arms. <kbd>E</kbd>

3.3 - I make the hand. <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

4.1 - To do the legs, I uncheck the box `clipping`.

4.2 - Only after unchecking the box, I extrude. <kbd>E</kbd>

4.3 - Then just move to the side, to separate the legs.

4.4 - I finish doing the leg and the feet. <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

I normally applied the mirror modifier after placing the bones, but as it gives error by applying it now or after placing the bones, I will apply it now.

[image]

5.1 - I create a bone and mark the mirror option.

5.2 - That way I just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to create two symmetrical bones.

5.3 - Then just go extruding normally.

5.4 - Even make the hand.

[image]

6.1 - To create the legs, I go in the lower part of the bone spine (the first one I created) and I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. (**I think the mistake may be there, see how that is created reflected, fat part with fat part, different from how the arms were created, fat part with lean part.**)

6.2 - Then just go extruding normally.

6.3 - Even make the foot.

[image]

7.1 - To create the neck I make an extrusion in the upper part of the bone of the spine (from which also the arms have left). <kbd>E</kbd>

7.2 - I extrude the bone from the head from the neck bone. <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

Notice from the image that the armor has **3 parents**. The spine bone `spine` (the one I created first) and the two bones of the thighs `spine_L.005` e `spine_R.005` (which I extrude by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to do the legs).

[image]

To end this problem and not to do so: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/109814/multiple-roots-are-found-in-the-bone-hierarchy-we.html

Just do the following:

[image]

Realize that you now have a father for everyone. If I move the bone spine, everyone will:

[image]

Now I attach mesh to the bone pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Association made successfully!

[image]

Now I'm going to do a little animation of 60 frames. It will consist of 0/30/60 key points, where at points 0 and 60 it will be in pose 1 and at point 30 it will be in pose 2. Then I intend to export it to UE4.

8.1 - I do your pose and I press <kbd>I</kbd>

8.2 - Then I copy your pose from frame 0, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

8.3 - Then I put it on frame 30, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (I learned it here on the same website, [Can an action be mirrored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/can-an-action-be-mirrored)).

8.4 - Then I usually stick to frame 60, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

9.1 - I change the screen to the action editor.

9.2 - I save by pressing F.

[image]

I export without modifying anything:

[image]

I want to know if I should change something at the time of exporting?

I saw this video and it's amazing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r986GDnpvXw&list=WL&index=116&

Soon it will help me.

I created a new project:

[image]

Let's go to import:

10.1 - I click on import.

10.2 - I select the object.

10.3 - I do not change anything and I click on import. (there are no skeletons selected)

10.4 - It gives you several warnings, but no mistakes at first. (for the first time, believe me)

10.5 - Three new things appear, but the animation I did did not appear.

[image]

Question object, links:

(**Before associate mesh with bone**) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iL-DTLL1U6SSXNOomBxoqy3-rNyVWOVQ/view?usp=sharing

(**After associate mesh with bone**) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9-Imj4NMOR42wWFl_gBw5_LnxhHcB5o/view?usp=sharing

(**After anim**) https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ztCVhCnlnpwrUG75XqKITy8MwJ1uLXR/view?usp=sharing

(**After export**) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNuaJrLDrVzeiP5UxbyB64h8p63bnIjn/view?usp=sharing

Questions I took a look at:

[Exporting fbx animations to ue4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24702/exporting-fbx-animations-to-ue4)

[Problem Exporting Rig/Character to UE4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/problem-exporting-rig-character-to-ue4)

---

EDIT 1

I created the UV map. <kbd>U</kbd>

[image]

I also activated Auto Smooth.

[image]

The UV map warning disappeared, but the other warnings continued, and a new warning appeared `Imported bone transform is different from original. Please check Output Log to see detail error.`

[image]

Links that helped me: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/116748/view.html and [Blender's "smoothing groups" solution (Edge Split) destroys topology. Is there an alternative solution?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/blenders-smoothing-groups-solution-edge-split-destroys-topology-is-there-a)

---

EDIT 2

By clicking on an arrow on the mesh tab, an option that solves one of the problems appears. Now the character's pose is the same as the frame 0 of the animation I did in Blender.

[image]

The bulletin board is much more compact.

[image]

Link that helped me: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/34041/t0-as-ref-pose-option.html

---

EDIT 3

At the time of export, just click on geometries and choose the smooth as face.

[image]

This last warning remains, but everything indicates that it is irrelevant.

[image]

Comment: Incredibly helpful for introducing how to make these - thanks so much

Comment: @HongPong Note that I still got some warnings / errors. I still haven't found a perfect way.